# QML components which have model / delegate reset when model is updated

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

Repeater, ListView kind of components which have model / delegate structure are completely resetting when an element within array is modified.

At the example below, the delegate is "Button and it's own Popup".

First, hover your mouse on the button, you will see that button is having the hover effect, changing color etc. Then two seconds later, when Timer is triggered, that hover effect will reset.

Second, click the button, Popup will open, then when Timer is triggered, Popup will close.

I am not sure if this is a bug or not. If it isn't then please recommend me a way to have a list which I can modify the elements and it won't reset.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    id: window
    width: 300
    height: 300
    color: "black"

    property var array: [0]

    Timer {
        running: true
        repeat: true
        interval: 2000
        onTriggered: {
            ++array[0]
            // Value won't change if it's not set to itself
            array = array
        }
    }

    // All "Item"s are being fully reset, at every update
    // the hover effect on button disappears,
    // and modal is being closed
    Repeater {
        model: array
        delegate: Item {
            Button {
                text: "Open My Popup"
                onClicked: modal.open()
            }

            Popup {
                id: modal
                anchors.centerIn: Overlay.overlay
                modal: true

                Text {
                    text: model.modelData
                    color: "white"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What does your _reset_ mean?

Comment: This is not a bug, this is standard behavior, since the array is a single "thing". You can use a `ListModel` and use append, set or any other function: [see doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html)

Comment: By reset I mean the hover effect starts from beginning, popup which is open is closing. Basically the item is being recreated.
@Amfasis I get the JSON from network every x seconds so I need to set it fully.

Comment: Use a QAbstractListModel, way more appropiate for this

Comment: Is there an example for this use-case?